# Function only works for the first condition

Tags: javascript

By pressing a button item ID passed to the function PIG element x and change its border when pressed when no border - by 2px, when pressing once again - border disappears. Works only the first condition. Help please.

```
function PIG(x) {

        if (!(document.getElementById(x).style.border = "none")) {

            document.getElementById(x).style.border = "2px solid green";

        }

        else if(!(document.getElementById(x).style.border = "2px solid green")){

            document.getElementById(x).style.border = "none";

        }
    }
```

Comment: `==` or `===` check equality. `=` is assignment. You just have a typo :(

Answer (score 2):

You're using an assignment operator when you should be using a comparison operator:

```
if (!(document.getElementById(x).style.border = "none")) {
```

Should be:

```
if (!(document.getElementById(x).style.border === "none")) {
// --------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: @KonstantinKolasau I can see a logical problem here - should the `!` operator really be there? By using it you basically mean "if there is border, apply border; if there is no border, remove the border". Remove the said operator and see if it works. Also, you probably don't need the `else if`, I think `else` would suffice in your case.

Comment: @rhino Your right the `!` operator should not be there ( after the comparison is added ). Otherwise they would go from `none` to `none` or `2px solid green` to `2px solid green` always. In other words it will never look different except mabye on the first call.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement will not work as you expect!

`if ( !(document.getElementById(x).style.border = "none"))`

It will **change** your border to none **instead of checking** the **border** **value to none** and breaks up a lot in your code logic!

Fix that first and log your values again.
I'm sure you will get the solution.

Fix first then rewrite/log your code:
`if (!(document.getElementById(x).style.border === "none"))`

Answer (score 0):

First as already pointed our you need to use the comparison operator `===` other than the assignment operator `=`. Second you have a logical error in your code, note that `!` means **not** So this:

```
    if (!(document.getElementById(x).style.border === "none")) {

        document.getElementById(x).style.border = "2px solid green";

    }

    else if(!(document.getElementById(x).style.border === "2px solid green")){

        document.getElementById(x).style.border = "none";

    }
```

Means:

```
/*
If the border is NOT "none" (In other words it's likely solid green)
    -> Make the border solid green
Otherwise if the border is NOT solid green (In other words it's likely none)
   -> Make the border none
*/
```

Obviously you want to remove the "NOT", so remove the not operators`!` in your code.

**[Here is a Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yhb51zwr/)**

Comment: @KonstantinKolasau In what way? It works fine in the example fiddle.